# switchyard soap binding in references

Tags: jboss

I am exploring `soap` binding switchyard in `jbds` in which I tried to give and get `SOAP` requests and responses.

I can forward a request to response using camel routing but can't manipulate the inputs(if any). Is it possible to use a java bean in the middle which could process the request and give some form of result?

Take for example a celsius to fahrenheit conversion, in which the request contains the celsius value while the conversion should happen in java bean and results are forwarded out as responses. I'm currently using soapui to send the soap requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it, by creating a switchyard message composition.
Please refer to [this](https://github.com/jboss-switchyard/quickstarts/tree/master/soap-addressing) example (WarehouseServiceImpl.java and WarehouseService.java).